# How to select data with specific conditions using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a database table which looks like:

[image]

In my code i call all the results in a for loop like this:

```
<?php  
  require 'database/connect.php';
  $pdores = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM excersises");

  foreach($pdores as $row) {
    echo "$row[2] ";
  }
?>
```

This gives me all the results under the row named excersise.
My problem is if i have an excersise with muscle_id 3 it will also display it. I only want to display the excersises with the muscle_id 1

So basically i want to display data on certain conditions, in this case when the muscle_id equals to 1.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks so much in advance,

Kevin

Comment: `select * from table WHERE YOUR CONDITION` At least try to use search, google or whatever before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you want:

```
 <?php  
      require 'database/connect.php';
    $muscle_id =1;
      $pdores = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM excersises where muscle_id=$muscle_id");

      foreach($pdores as $row) {
        echo "$row[2] ";
      }
    ?>
```